# What changed about webpack, babel, and React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I can no longer do a simplified webpack build, and I don't understand why...

#### app.js

```
var React = require("react");

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <div>Hello World</div>;
    }

}

React.render(<App />, document.body);
```

#### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

#### run...

`$ webpack`

#### causes error...

```
ERROR in ./app.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/alexbanks/Documents/code-play-2/eslint/app.js: Unexpected token (6:15)
  4 | 
  5 |     render() {
> 6 |         return <div>Hello World</div>;
    |                ^
  7 |     }
  8 | 
  9 | }
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/alexbanks/Documents/code-play-2/eslint/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:22:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/alexbanks/Documents/code-play-2/eslint/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:91:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/Users/alexbanks/Documents/code-play-2/eslint/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:510:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/alexbanks/Documents/code-play-2/eslint/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:265:19)
```

## ???

This is something that used to build.  I've tried using react-dom, I have babel-loader, babel-core, and react installed.  I've tried several variations of the code includeing React.createComponent... everything gives me the same error.  My project only has 3 files, **app.js**, **webpack.config.js**, and **index.html**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did an npm update it is probably babel 6. Here are the changes for that.

```js
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "latest",
    "babel-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "latest",
    "babel-preset-react": "latest",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "latest",
```

```js
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {presets:[ 'es2015', 'react', 'stage-0' ]}
      },
```